# Не могу запустить тест из терминала Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, юнит-тесты, junit

У меня есть одно [тестовое задание](https://github.com/driversti/audit-reporter-blank). Мне необходимо добавить к нему тестирование. Я создал один тест и он прекрасно запускается в Intellij IDEA. Но! Мне необходимо выполнить тест с терминала Ubuntu. И у меня это никак не выходит. Компиляцию проходит успешно. Вот один пример команды, которой запускаю:

```
~/audit-reporter-blank$ java -cp .:/usr/local/JUNIT/junit-4.12.jar:/usr/local/JUNIT/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test/UnitTest
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0.006
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [test/UnitTest]
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test/UnitTest
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

ещё один

```
~/audit-reporter-blank$ java -cp .:/usr/local/JUNIT/junit-4.12.jar:/usr/local/JUNIT/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/driversti/audit-reporter-blank/src/com/egnyte/utils/auditreporter/Runner.class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test/UnitTest
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0.008
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [test/UnitTest]
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test/UnitTest
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

и ещё один

```
~/audit-reporter-blank/test$ java -cp .:/usr/local/JUNIT/junit-4.12.jar:/usr/local/JUNIT/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore UnitTest
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0.007
There was 1 failure:
1) testFillList(UnitTest)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/egnyte/utils/auditreporter/Runner
at UnitTest.testFillList(UnitTest.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:77)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.egnyte.utils.auditreporter.Runner
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 30 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

Первые два запускал из корня проекта, второй из папки test, так как отказывается находить test/UnitTest. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно запустить тест с терминала?

Comment: не знаю в чем у вас проблема. но могу посоветовать оформить проект в виде стандартной структуры maven или grandle  проекта  и запускать тесты командой `mvn test`.

Comment: С maven всё значительно проще, но хотелось бы запустить с консоли без него

Comment: Добавьте в classpath скомпилированные классы для которых написан тест.